# Is it possible to add suffix via C macros to certain strings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, generics, macros

I have an Objective-C lightweight generic type declaration, say

```
NSArray<NSNumber *> *array;
```

I simplified it into

```
#define Array(X) NSArray<X *> *
Array(NSNumber) array;
```

So far so good. But it won't work with nested arrays, like

```
// wrong, it'll be parsed to NSArray<NSArray<NSNumber *> * *> *
// one extra star being added while nesting...
Array(Array(NSNumber)) array;
```

#### My question is, is it possible to determine if the macro should add a star to the end of the input parameter?